# Aggregate all items of an array inside an object Mongo/Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I have this aggregate publish function from the meteor reactive aggregate package. I'm trying to aggregate all values in the Matches array. Not sure where in the function I need to specify the array for the aggregation (reading the docs I am not sure exactly where). I also tried a few things unsuccessfully.

Publish aggregation

```
Meteor.publish('reportTotals', function() {
ReactiveAggregate(this, Players, [{
//grouping the items
$group: {
  '_id': this.userId,
  'score': {
    $sum: '$score'
  },
  'assists': {
    $sum: '$assists'
  }
}
}, {
$project: {
  score: '$score',
  assists: '$assists'
}
 }], {
     clientCollection: 'playerReport'
  });
});
```

And this is an example of an object where there might be multiple matches that I need to compile the scores, assists, ect.

```
{  "_id": "WhrZCTtj9HHtDB3rs",
   "name": "Test player",
   "team": "TThqi8Wu6YJh6mapC",
   "practicesAttended": 3,
   "createdBy": "RKtpy532sgzbBpP4J",
   "createdAt": "2016-05-29T16:26:47.837Z",
   "notes": "Small test notes",
   "itemImage": "Lfb27GnWXDRxfkajL",
   "Matches": [
    {
      "match": "2016-05-21",
      "score": 3,
      "shotsTaken": 4,
      "assists": 0,
      "duelsWon": 4,
      "duelsLost": 2,
      "tacklesWon": 0,
      "tacklesLost": 0,
      "blocks": 51
    }
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator, it will develop or flatten embedded arrays into several unique elements. So for each input document, it outputs `n` documents where `n` is the number of array elements and can be zero for an empty array.

**Note**: The field name, on which **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** is applied, should be prefixed with `$` (dollar sign)

In your case above, pipe **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** to **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)**. This is similar to using `LEFT JOIN ... GROUP BY` in `SQL`:

```
Meteor.publish('reportTotals', function() {
    ReactiveAggregate(this, Players, [
        // unwind the Matches list
        { "$uniwnd": "$Matches" },
        //grouping the items
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": this.userId,
                "score": { "$sum": "$Matches.score" },
                "assists": { "$sum": "$Matches.assists" }
            }
        }
    ], { clientCollection: 'playerReport' });
});
```

Comment: thanks for this quick answer. When I create a helper function that returns the *playerReport* collection the console spits _ReferenceError: playerReport is not defined_. I do subscribe to *reportTotals* and this is my function `reportTotals: function() { return playerReport.find(); }` am I missing something?

Comment: and yes the collection is created and I do see it in meteor toys, for some reason I can't pull it in the view and do an {{#each reportTotals}} to pull the {{score}} and {{assists}}... :(